# Curve hooks messing up after movement

Tags: rigging, bezier-curves, parent, curve-modifier, hook-modifier

On this model I used curves and curve modifier to create these tubes and I thought using hooks is a reasonable attempt to animate them

[image: Mask with tubes connected to smt on the chest]

I'm not that experienced with the hook modifier but I tweaked the strength here and there to achieve this setup where I can move the head and my curves can work with my rig in harmony

[image: Head rotated a bit with tubes moving fine]

But! the problem only shows itself when you try to move the whole thing. for some reason the hooks really wanna stay where they are despite being parented to other bones and objects?

[image: idk what to say really]

I mean they are moving but the curves that are hooked to them, well not so much. I looked up some manuals and tutorials trying to see how others deal with this but well, no one moves them as a whole I guess. Tnx for reading this far.